# Selecting a dropdown option from webbrowser

Tags: c#

My goal I need to select the second option.

I've tried following approach and can't set selected value. No error shows up, the selection just doesn't happen.  Being very familiar with HTML myself, I know that "selected" and 'selected="selected"' work but not sure why it's not working with my C# code. What could be wrong?

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("field_gender1").
       Children[1].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

The HTML is

```
<select name="gender1" id="field_gender1" class="select">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">val1</option>
        <option value="2">val2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Comment: Can you please provide what the error itself it?

Comment: Try removing `selected` attribute from the first option. Otherwise you have 2 selected options at the same time.

Comment: No error shows up, the selection just doesn't happen. As for elaboration - well I need to select the second option however all ways i've tried is not happening.

Comment: Didn't work, being very familiar with HTML myself, I know that "selected" & 'selected="selected"' work but not sure why it's not working with this, any other possible options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be working if it's at a suitable place, eg: button1_Click event, webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted event, etc.

Comment: It's in webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted, all other text entering, checking boxes and so on work fine, so thats strange

Comment: That's definitely strange. Do you have any try-catch block?

Comment: Whats that? Haven't heard of it

Comment: Usually we encapsulate a block of codes inside a try-catch block in order to handle possible error occurred during runtime. However, if it's implemented improperly you may not able to see the real error in your application. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx) is some reference to try-catch block.

Answer (score 7):

Do this from WebBrowser_DocumentComplete(...)

```
var htmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  if (htmlDocument != null)
  {
     var dropdown = ((IHTMLElement)htmlDocument.all.item("field_gender1"));
     var dropdownItems = (IHTMLElementCollection)dropdown.children;

     foreach(IHTMLElement option in dropdownItems)
     {
        var value = option.getAttribute("value").ToString();
        if(value.Equals("2"))
           option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
     }

  }
```