# c# selecting a drop down option with webbrowser

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a "web formula filler", however I have a problem with selecting an value from drop down list. I'm trying to select options for "date of birth" on this site: https://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/

I've tried with multiple options, however everything failed. I have found source code for similar problem, and it was working like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay").SetAttribute("value", "10")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthMonth").SetAttribute("value", "12")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthYear").SetAttribute("value", "1990")
```

However it doesn't work. Anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Use the answer from Dzenad at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257756/c-sharp-selecting-a-drop-down-option-from-webbrowser

Comment: I think you mean "web form filler", not "formula filler" - the two are quite different.

Comment: If you feel duplicate is not enough make sure to provide [MCVE] inline in the post and comment to re-open.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML (and the DOM), only `<input />` elements's `value=""` attribute matters - but drop-down inputs are actually `<select>` elements, not `<input />`, so there is no `value=""` attribute to use, instead you use the `<option selected="selected">` attribute.

```
var daySelect = WebBrowser1.Documents.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay");
var day10Option = daySelect.Children.Single( e => e.Value == "10" );
day10Option.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

...repeat for however many `<select>` elements you want. Note I'm assuming the `.Single` linq extension method works in your DOM library, I might be wrong, but you should be able to infer it yourself.

Comment: Thank you bro for your comment, however as you said   .Single doesn't work. However I will try to fix it. If anynone has ideas to solve it, I would be grateful:)