# c# selecting a listbox option with webbrowser

Tags: c#, listbox

Im trying to write an application where web form will be filled with one click. The problem is that I can't get working picking one option from listbox, here is HTML code I'm facing:

```
 <select name="data[PvpnetAccount][date_of_birth_day]" id="PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay" class="ignore_keyup c-signup__input c-signup__input--select c-form-group__input c-form-group__input--select js-selectize">
                                <option value="" disabled selected >Day</option>
                                <option value="01">1</option>
                                <option value="02">2</option>
                                <option value="03">3</option>
                                <option value="04">4</option>
                                <option value="05">5</option>
                                <option value="06">6</option>
                                <option value="07">7</option>
                                <option value="08">8</option>
                                <option value="09">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>
                            </select>
```

I have tried with different options, but nothing gave me results so far, so I'm up for any suggestions. My first try was:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay").SetAttribute("value", "03");
```

However Im aware that it won't work.

EDIT:
A guy advised me to do this like this:

```
var daySelect = WebBrowser1.Documents.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay");
var day10Option = daySelect.Children.Single( e => e.Value == "10" );
day10Option.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

However it seems like **.Single** gives me error.

Comment: That should work, are you waiting for the document to fully load?

Comment: Yeah, even I have setted 10 seconds delay :> It won't work so easy :/

Answer (score 0):

Just as a precaution for test purposes to make sure that page loaded correctly and you got correct element selected look at `outerHTML` property of the element. Also, are you executing this code on background worker, if yes you will need to use `Action` let me know if you need more instructions on that. Also try using `IHTMLSelectElement` instead of `HtmlElement`. To use it add reference to

> Microsoft.mshtml

and add `using mshtml;` to your file. After you can do the following:

`HtmlElement tmp = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PvpnetAccountDateOfBirthDay");
IHTMLSelectElement tComboBox = (IHTMLSelectElement)tmp.DomElement;
tComboBox.selectedIndex = 2;`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried your code, but it isn't working. BTW I will post my code so far in next post.

Comment: Look to this answer [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257756/selecting-a-dropdown-option-from-webbrowser look at @Dzenad 's answer. Also some dropdown's elements are clickable buttons, try to click them. Can you provide link to the page, so I can try on my end.

Comment: Will look arround, meanwhile here is the link:
[link](https://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/)